# pigpio.error: 'no permission to update GPIO' Only on some pins

Tags: python, pigpio

I am having an issue where I get this error 'no permission to update GPIO'. whenever I try to address certain gpio pins. I looked at other posts that had similar issues but they seemed to have either permission issues in which case no gpio works or not be using Broadcom pin numbers which is not the case here. The following code throws the error for the two lines with pin 13 but not 18.  ultimately I want to use the hardware pwm which as best I can tell needs these two pins to work.

```py
    import pigpio
    pi = pigpio.pi()

    pi.set_mode(18, 2) # no error here
    print(pi.get_mode(18))

    pi.set_mode(13, 2) # error here
    print(pi.get_mode(13))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get that error if pigpio decides that you should not be writing to that GPIO.

Typically it means you are trying to write to a GPIO **which is not connected to the expansion header on the model of Pi running pigpio**.

In this case GPIO 13 is only available on the compute module or the Pis with a 40 pin expansion header.

Comment: Thanks. turns out it was an older raspberry pi then I thought it was and did not actually have the 40 pin expansion